# How do I set up a new key combination?

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout, 19.04

I'm running 19.04. I have a US keyboard on my laptop, but I used Hungarian layout back on Windows.

There, Ctrl + Alt + V was the "@" sign. The built in hungarian layout is fine but I'm missing the "@" sign.

How do I set it up so that when I type Ctrl + Alt + V, I get the charachter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that on Linux a combination like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> would be a shortcut for some command and not for typing.

However, the good news is that the @ character is even more easily accessible with the Hungarian keyboard layout:

<kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> => @

( <kbd>AltGr</kbd> is the same as <kbd>Right Alt</kbd> )